# I added a proxy to Selenium and now the page won't open [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

My bot successfully worked on my local network.
But by adding proxies as if lost connection to the network...

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep

# SMM Setup
VIDEO = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjiUC8jeF1o'
VIEWS = 20

# PROBLEM SETUP
PROXIES = [
    '0.0.0.0:0000',
    '0.0.0.0:0000',
    '0.0.0.0:0000',
    '0.0.0.0:0000',
    '0.0.0.0:0000',
    '0.0.0.0:0000',
    '0.0.0.0:0000',
    '0.0.0.0:0000',
    '0.0.0.0:0000',
    '0.0.0.0:0000'
]
YOUTUBE_ACCEPT_COOKIES_A = '/html/body/ytd-app/ytd-consent-bump-v2-lightbox/tp-yt-paper-dialog/div[4]/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/ytd-button-renderer[2]/a/tp-yt-paper-button'
YOUTUBE_ACCEPT_COOKIES_B = '/html/body/ytd-app/ytd-consent-bump-v2-lightbox/tp-yt-paper-dialog/div[4]/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/ytd-button-renderer[2]/yt-button-shape/button'

# start - 153

# Init
global driver

# Create Views
for x in range(len(PROXIES)):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXIES[x])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/sasha/OneDrive/Desktop/CHROME_DRIVER/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options = options)
    driver.get(VIDEO)
    for y in range(VIEWS / PROXIES):
        driver.refresh()
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, YOUTUBE_ACCEPT_COOKIES_A))).click()
        except TimeoutException:
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, YOUTUBE_ACCEPT_COOKIES_B))).click()
            except:
                print('Any Cookie Accepts Not Found')
        sleep(2)
    driver.quit()

# Close All Tabs
driver.quit()
```

I tried to remove chrome_options = options. It worked.
But I can't use my local network for some reason.

Comment: we don't have access to your local network - so we have no idea what is the problem. Free proxies often don't work or they are on blacklists of big portals and they can block access using `proxy`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I found the problem and solved it!
When I added my proxies to the list, I copied them from my email message. All proxies ports were 4444, but in the website profile was 12345.
I changed 4444 to 12345 and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change port

Example: 4444 to 12345 / 55555